# Moving the content of a folder to another one

Tags: file, delphi, winapi, move

Using Delphi 7, I need to move all the content (files, folders and subfolders) from one folder to another one. After some research, SHFileOpStruct seems to be the best option. Here is what I got so far:

```
function MoveDir(SrcDir, DstDir: string): Boolean;
var
  FOS: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@FOS, SizeOf(FOS));
  with FOS do
  begin
    wFunc  := FO_MOVE; // FO_COPY;
    fFlags := FOF_FILESONLY or
      FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS;
    pFrom  := PChar(SrcDir + #0);
    pTo    := PChar(DstDir + #0);
  end;
  Result := (SHFileOperation(FOS) = 0);
end;
```

But when using this function, the entire folder is moved to destination, not only it content. For example, if I use MoveDir('c:\test', 'd:\test') I get d:\teste\teste.

I already tried to change this line bellow, and it works when coping the files (FO_COPY) but not when moving.

```
pFrom  := PChar(SrcDir + '\*.*' + #0);
```

Please, can someone help me with this? Would be great if I can do this without moving file by file, folder by folder...

Thanks!!

Comment: Your code (second version, with `'\*.*'`) works for me, just by removing `FOF_FILESONLY` flag... what Windows version are you using and what error code is returned?

Comment: @GabrielF, you are right! The problem was the "FOF_FILESONLY" flag... Please, add your answer for me to accept... Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use your second version, without `FOF_FILESONLY` flag:

```
function MoveDir(SrcDir, DstDir: string): Boolean;
var
  FOS: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@FOS, SizeOf(FOS));
  with FOS do
  begin
    wFunc  := FO_MOVE; // FO_COPY;
    fFlags := FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS;
    pFrom  := PChar(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SrcDir) + '*.*'#0);
    pTo    := PChar(DstDir + #0);
  end;
  Result := (SHFileOperation(FOS) = 0);
end;
```